# Want to render a 3D mri image in Blender, either in nii.gz format or numpy array

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, image

I have 3D mri images in niftii format that can be converted into numpy array, and i wanted to know what the best way to render them in Blender (or any other 3D software really). Matplotlib and mayavi haven’t really been cutting it for me, and i feel like this is a rather straightforward problem without a straightforward answer?

And another thing i was wondering was whether i could overlay two of these images on top of each other, or would it be best to transform the two into one voxel to render.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Blender's voxel interface isn't the greatest. Have you tried pyqtgraph to display the 3D data?

Comment: If you can convert them into an EXR image (by combining each slice) then you can render them using a Volume Scatter or Principled Volume shader - see https://baldingwizard.wixsite.com/blog/smoke2exr for an example of an add-on that takes a smoke domain and does exactly that. This does depend on the resolution being used as you need to be able to create a single image that contains all of the tiled 'layers' of the "domain".

Comment: @Leander i have not, i will try that!